# Error: line contains NULL byte

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 282, in load_iris
    temp = next(data_file)
Error: line contains NULL byte
```

What shall I do to remove this error?
I am trying to import my dataset of arrhythmia for training by replacing iris datafile in sklearn datasets and using load_iris function.

Comment: Where did your data file come from?  How was it made?  Are you sure it's a genuine file?

Comment: from UCI repository, and I have converted it in csv, unicode formt, what do u mean by genuine?

Comment: I mean, are you sure the file contains the correct contents?  The error message indicates that the file contains a NULL byte which is a no-no.  One plausible explanation is that your code is correct, but the file is wrong somehow.  You say you "converted" it.  How did you do that, exactly?  Perhaps your conversion process introduced an error.

Comment: using excel and notepad++